# How to create CDK NestedStack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a CDK deployment that uses nested stacks:

```ts
// app
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import { PipelineParentStack } from '../lib/pipeline-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
const pipelines : string = app.node.tryGetContext("pipelines");
new PipelineParentStack(app, 'PipelineParentStack', {
    pipelines: pipelines
});
```

The `pipelines` string contains a comma-separated list for which we should create a nested stack for each element.

```ts
// nested stacks sit within parent stack
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import cfn = require('@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation');
import {Construct} from "@aws-cdk/core";

interface PipelineParentStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  pipelines: string;
}

export class PipelineParentStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: PipelineParentStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    if (props) {
      const pipelinesArray = props.pipelines.split(",");
      for (let pipeline of pipelinesArray) {
        new PipelineStack(scope, pipeline)
      }
    }
  }
}

export class PipelineStack extends cfn.NestedStack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cfn.NestedStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here
  }
}
```

When I try to deploy the parent stack, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/pipeline/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation/lib/nested-stack.ts:227

throw new Error(`Nested stacks must be defined within scope of another non-nested stack`);
^
Error: Nested stacks must be defined within scope of another non-nested stack
at findParentStack (/tmp/pipeline/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation/lib/nested-stack.ts:227:11)
at new NestedStack (/tmp/pipeline/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation/lib/nested-stack.ts:87:25)
at new PipelineStack (/src/function/pipeline/lib/pipeline-stack.ts:24:5)
at new PipelineParentStack (/src/function/pipeline/lib/pipeline-stack.ts:16:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/src/function/pipeline/bin/pipeline.ts:8:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

This appears to me to be configured as per the documentation here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-cloudformation

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the `scope` of the nested stacks to the parent stack (`this` since it is being defined in the parent constructor), so change the nested stack definition to:

```ts
new PipelineStack(this, pipeline)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the doc about usage of [nested stack of Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-cloudformation-readme.html#nested-stacks).

Though this feature is marked as stable, there is still having [block issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4474) for using it. You can NOT share the VPC declaration among nested stacks!

Comment: That issue has been resolved, and the documentation linked to has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this? Sorry if it didn't work.  I didn't try it out. Just based on the error, this needs to be in the scope of parent stack.

new PipelineStack(this, pipeline);